Assessing the homogeneity of a dendrogram
I'm developing a model that organises items of different classes into a dendrogram, like the one here:
A dendrogram showing items of 6 different classes
I'm wondering how I can assess the homogeneity (or heterogeneity) of this dendrogram. To illustrate this, consider the following two dendrograms:
Dendrograms with high and low "homogeneity"
The first one (right) shows high “homogeneity”, since items of the some colour (class) are nicely grouped together. The second one (left), shows low homogeneity, since the items with the same colour are not close at all.
To make matters more complex, the distance between the groups matters, too. Consider the following two dendrograms:
Dendrograms with medium and low "homogeneity"
While both dendrograms would have a low-ish homogeneity, the one on the right displays the lower homogeneity, since $x_1$ is farer away from $x_2$ than in the first one.
So, what is a good measure to assess the "homogeneity" of my dendrograms, which takes into account the caveats mentioned above.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Cross-posted: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/470228/assessing-the-homogeneity-of-a-dendrogram Please note that cross-posting violates SE policy.
